# unable to open interactive shell for vertex ai custom training job

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-tpu, vertex-ai-pipeline

It happens on custom training job with tpu_v2 in us-central1. I followed "launch web terminal" link under training debugging in custom training job UI, but got the following message.

I should have the necessary permissions as I started the custom training job, through vertex ai pipeline as part of kubeflow pipeline. My docker image should also have bash as its entry point calls bash.

```
runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Operation not permitted                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
SIGABRT: abort                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PC=0x7f3b932d7a7c m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
goroutine 0 [idle]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
runtime: g 0: unknown pc 0x7f3b932d7a7c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
stack: frame={sp:0x7fff78eca340, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7fff786cb8c0,0x7fff78eca8d0)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
0x00007fff78eca240:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca250:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca260:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000       
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0x00007fff78eca370:  0x00007fff78eca4be  0x00007fff78eca4bf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca380:  0x0000000000000000  0x00007f3b932d5759                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca390:  0x00000000007fff00  0x0000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca3a0:  0x00000000003d0f00  0x00007f3b6bea8910                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca3b0:  0x00007f3b6bea8910  0x00007f3b6bea8910                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca3c0:  0x0000000000000000  0x71c8cb3b369b8900                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca3d0:  0x00007f3b9323e740  0x0000000000000006                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca3e0:  0x0000564c9f37f7db  0x00007fff78eca710                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca3f0:  0x0000564c9fd99420  0x00007f3b93283476                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca400:  0x00007f3b9345be90  0x00007f3b932697f3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca410:  0x0000000000000020  0x0000000000000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca420:  0x00007f3b6bea8640  0x00007f3b932d65c4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0x00007fff78eca430:  0x00007fff78eca468  0x00007fff78eca650                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
goroutine 1 [running]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
runtime.systemstack_switch()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:463 fp=0xc000132780 sp=0xc000132778 pc=0x564c9e777d20                                                                                                                                                                                        
runtime.main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:170 +0x6d fp=0xc0001327e0 sp=0xc000132780 pc=0x564c9e748c2d                                                                                                                                                                                      
runtime.goexit()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 +0x1 fp=0xc0001327e8 sp=0xc0001327e0 pc=0x564c9e779fc1                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
rax    0x0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
rbx    0x7f3b9323e740                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
rcx    0x7f3b932d7a7c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
rdx    0x6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
rdi    0x6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
rsi    0x6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
rbp    0x6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
rsp    0x7fff78eca340                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
r8     0x7fff78eca410                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
r9     0x7fffffff                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
r10    0x8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
r11    0x246                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
r12    0x6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
r13    0x16                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
r14    0x564c9fd99420                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
r15    0x1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
rip    0x7f3b932d7a7c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
rflags 0x246                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
cs     0x33                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
fs     0x0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
gs     0x0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[Finished... Terminado]
```